# Best way to handle image with multiple sub-images in Emgu+OpenCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am working on a C# app that is using Emgu and OpenCV, both are version 2.9.0. I am a beginner with OpenCV/Emgu and I need some help to get me going.

I have a large image that contains multiple sub-images. Each of the sub-images contain a number of regions which needs to be processed with OpenCV in different ways.

The large image is updated several times per second. I am planning on using pInvoke and memcpy to update the bitmap of the large image. In order to avoid multiple copy operations, I want the sub-images to share pixel data with the large image, so they automatically get new pixel data when the large image is updated.

Sub-images will be processed simultaneously in multiple parallel threads.

What I need to know is the best way to organize the large image vs. sub-images and regions to be processed so I can update the pixels with one call to memcpy and then process regions in sub-images on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explained why you want to use sub-images of a larger image instead of using several classic images, so I assume there is a good reason.

I think the only way for doing this is by stacking sub-images vertically. Indeed, OpenCV images are stored row by row in memory, hence the only way to make sub-images share pixel data with the large image *while* being able to efficiently process the sub-images is if the sub-images and large image have the same rows. If you do this, you can use `Mat::rowRange()` to extract sub-images of type `Mat`, that you can then process as you wish.